# Custom Code Analysis?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, is it possible to create my own rules to be checked as part of Static Code Analysis?

View > Tool Windows > Messages > Code Analysis

e.g., I might like to make a rule to verify that lines of code aren't longer than 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [checkstyle plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065).